# how to tokenize string to array of int in c?

Tags: c, arrays, numbers

Anyone got anything about reading a sequential number from text file per line and parsing it to an array in C?

What I have in a file:

```
12 3 45 6 7 8
3 5 6 7
7 0 -1 4 5
```

What I want in my program:

```
array1[] = {12, 3, 45, 6, 7, 8};
array2[] = {3, 5, 6, 7};
array3[] = {7, 0, -1, 4, 5};
```

I've been through several ways to read it, but the only matter is only when i want to tokenize it per line.
Thank you.

Comment: thanks for all,
but now i realize that the the problem is to tokenize.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following code will read a file a line at a time

```
char line[80]
FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
while(fgets(line,1,fp) != null)
{
   // do something
}
fclose(fp);
```

You can then tokenise the input using [strtok()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-s-strtok-s-l-wcstok-s-wcstok-s-l-mbstok-s-mbstok-s-l) and [sscanf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sscanf-sscanf-l-swscanf-swscanf-l) to convert the text to numbers.

From the MSDN page for sscanf:

> Each of these functions [sscanf and swscanf] returns the
>   number of fields successfully
>   converted and assigned; the return
>   value does not include fields that
>   were read but not assigned. A return
>   value of 0 indicates that no fields
>   were assigned. The return value is EOF
>   for an error or if the end of the
>   string is reached before the first
>   conversion.

The following code will convert the string to an array of integers. Obviously for a variable length array you'll need a list or some scanning the input twice to determine the length of the array before actually parsing it.

```
char tokenstring[] = "12 23 3 4 5";
char seps[] = " ";
char* token;
int var;
int input[5];
int i = 0;

token = strtok (tokenstring, seps);
while (token != NULL)
{
    sscanf (token, "%d", &var);
    input[i++] = var;

    token = strtok (NULL, seps);
}
```

Putting:

```
char seps[]   = " ,\t\n";
```

will allow the input to be more flexible.

*I had to do a search to remind myself of the syntax - I found it [here in the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fgets-fgetws)*

Comment: could you show me how to use sscanf() for a unknown total of numbers per line in order to parse it to an array?

Comment: @ChrisF the idea i found here is to use int var for temporary use, btw, thank you very much.

Comment: @ChrisF is there a way to get this to handle 1,2,,4?

Comment: @cokedude - it's been a while since I've done c in anger so I don't think I can help you here. I'm sure there's a simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to make a function like this:

```
size_t read_em(FILE *f, int **a);
```

In the function, allocate some memory to the pointer `*a`, then start reading numbers from the `f` and storing them in `*a`. When you encounter a newline character, simply return the number of elements you've stored in `*a`. Then, call it like this:

```
int *a = NULL;
FILE *f = fopen("Somefile.txt", "r");
size_t len = read_em(f, &a);
// now a is an array, and len is the number of elements in that array
```

Useful functions:

- [`malloc()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) to allocate an array.
- [`realloc()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html) to extend a `malloc()`ed array
- [`fgets()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) to read a line of text (or as much as can be stored).
- [`sscanf()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sscanf.html) to read data from a string (such as a string returned by `fgets()`) into other variables (such as an `int` array created by `malloc()` - hint hint)

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly suggest NOT to use sscanf and friends when the number of fields is variable.
Use [strtok](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/) and [atoi](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/atoi/).  Just make sure to read the strtok manpage well, many programmers I know find its syntax a bit surprising in the beginning.  Also note that strtok will modify the input string, so you may want to work on a copy.

Comment: better yet: use `strtol()` so you won't need `strtok()`

Answer (score 1):

The following code may be what you're looking for. Hopefully you won't need too much of a description given the comments but, if you have questions, feel free to ask.

It basically uses an `fgets` loop to read each line in and `strtok` to separate that line into fields. It constructs a linked list of integer arrays which contain the actual data - you can see the use of that linked list in the code at the end that dumps out the table.

It also has a means by which it can handle arbitrary-sized lines in the input file without buffer overflow (subject to memory constraints of course). Keep in mind that the `strtok` only expects one space between each field on the line although that *could* be recoded to handle multiple spaces or even any amount of white space. I've kept that bit simple since the code was already getting a little big :-)

The `atoi` function is used to convert the individual word on each line into integers. If you want error checking on those, I'd call your own variant which also checks that all characters in the word are numeric.

Using your input file of:

```
12 3 45 6 7 8
3 5 6 7
7 0 -1 4 5
```

it produces output along the lines of:

```
0x97b5170, size = 6:
   12 3 45 6 7 8
0x97b51d0, size = 4:
   3 5 6 7
0x97b51e0, size = 5:
   7 0 -1 4 5
```

Here's the code that produced that output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

// This is the linked list of integer arrays.

typedef struct _tIntArray {
    int size;
    int *array;
    struct _tIntArray *next;
} tIntArray;
static tIntArray *first = NULL;
static tIntArray *last = NULL;

// Add a line of integers as a node.

static int addNode (char *str) {
    tIntArray *curr;  // pointers for new integer array.
    char *word;       // word within string.
    char *tmpStr;     // temp copy of buffer.
    int fldCnt;       // field count for line.
    int i;

    // Count number of fields.

    if ((tmpStr = strdup (str)) == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot allocate duplicate string (%d).\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    fldCnt = 0;
    for (word = strtok (tmpStr, " "); word; word = strtok (NULL, " "))
        fldCnt++;
    free (tmpStr);
```

```
    // Create new linked list node.

    if ((curr = malloc (sizeof (tIntArray))) == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot allocate integer array node (%d).\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    curr->size = fldCnt;
    if ((curr->array = malloc (fldCnt * sizeof (int))) == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot allocate integer array (%d).\n", errno);
        free (curr);
        return 1;
    }
    curr->next = NULL;

    for (i = 0, word = strtok (str, " "); word; word = strtok (NULL, " "))
        curr->array[i++] = atoi (word);

    if (last == NULL)
        first = last = curr;
    else {
        last->next = curr;
        last = curr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
int main(void) {
    int lineSz;       // current line size.
    char *buff;       // buffer to hold line.
    FILE *fin;        // input file handle.
    long offset;      // offset for re-allocating line buffer.
    tIntArray *curr;  // pointers for new integer array.
    int i;

    // Open file.

    if ((fin = fopen ("qq.in", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot open qq.in, errno = %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate initial line.

    lineSz = 2;
    if ((buff = malloc (lineSz+1)) == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot allocate initial memory, errno = %d.\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    // Loop forever.

    while (1) {
        // Save offset in case we need to re-read.

        offset = ftell (fin);
```

```
        // Get line, exit if end of file.

        if (fgets (buff, lineSz, fin) == NULL)
            break;

        // If no newline, assume buffer wasn't big enough.

        if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
            // Get bigger buffer and seek back to line start and retry.

            free (buff);
            lineSz += 3;
            if ((buff = malloc (lineSz+1)) == NULL) {
                printf ("Cannot allocate extra memory, errno = %d.\n", errno);
                return 1;
            }
            if (fseek (fin, offset, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
                printf ("Cannot seek, errno = %d.\n", errno);
                return 1;
            }
            continue;
        }

        // Remove newline and process.

        buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
        if (addNode (buff) != 0)
            return 1;
    }
```

```
    // Dump table for debugging.

    for (curr = first; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        printf ("%p, size = %d:\n  ", curr, curr->size);
        for (i = 0; i < curr->size; i++)
            printf (" %d", curr->array[i]);
        printf ("\n");
    }

    // Free resources and exit.

    free (buff);
    fclose (fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your file have a specific number of lines or do you need to be able to read an arbitrary number into random arrays?

Here's code to read in a file line by line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *inname = "test.txt";
    FILE *infile;
    char line_buffer[BUFSIZ];

    infile = fopen(inname, "r");
    if (!infile) {
        printf("Couldn't open file %s for reading.\n", inname);
        return 0;
    }

    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), infile)) {
        // process line
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can use `sscanf` or any of a number of tokenizing/converting functions to extract the numbers.  `BUFSIZ` is a good constant from `stdio.h` that is designed to make stream I/O efficient on a target system.

Comment: Why are you storing a `line_number` as a `char` type? Do you want to be inherently limited to 127 lines?

Comment: could you show me how to extract the numbers by using sscanf?

Comment: line_number shouldn't even be in there, it's an artifact from some other code...removed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtol()` to parse each line:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    static char buffer[1024];
    static long values[256];

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
    {
        char *current = buffer;
        size_t i = 0;
        while(*current && *current != '\n' &&
            i < sizeof values / sizeof *values)
        {
            char *tail = NULL;
            errno = 0;
            values[i] = strtol(current, &tail, 0);

            if(errno || tail == current)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to parse %s\n", current);
                break;
            }

            ++i, current = tail;
        }

        // process values
        printf("read %i values\n", i);
    }
}
```