# How to extract words from a sentence efficiently in C?

Tags: c, string, substring

I need an efficient function that extracts first second and rest of the sentence into three variables.

Comment: Tis a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483206/how-to-tokenize-string-to-array-of-int-in-c/ - but not exact

Comment: "on-disk" is one word or two words?

Comment: Do you mean that the algorithm would take "abcd" and split it into 'a', 'b', and "cd" ?

Comment: No. "cat eats many rats" should give "cat", "eats" and "many rats"

Comment: Ok then, my solution should work. Give it a try.

Comment: I fixed the example, try it again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easy way: Use [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) or strtok_r to get the first two tokens, which will remove them from the string, so the string itself will be your third token you were looking for.

Hard way: Parse it yourself :(

Strtok is in the C string library, and will mutate your original string so be careful, copy the string first if it needs to remain intact.

Possible Example:

```
//#include <string.h>

char input[] ="first second third forth";
char delimiter[] = " ";
char *firstWord, *secondWord, *remainder, *context;

int inputLength = strlen(input);
char *inputCopy = (char*) calloc(inputLength + 1, sizeof(char));
strncpy(inputCopy, input, inputLength);

firstWord = strtok_r (inputCopy, delimiter, &context);
secondWord = strtok_r (NULL, delimiter, &context);
remainder = context;

printf("%s\n", firstWord);
printf("%s\n", secondWord);
printf("%s\n", remainder);

getchar();
free(inputCopy);
```

This should work just fine and be threadsafe with the original string unmutated.

Comment: Another gotcha is that strtok() uses an internal static variable, so it is not thread safe.  Use strtok_r() if that's an issue.

Comment: Very true, changed example to use strtok_r

Comment: Its giving me first token in reminder and not the remaining sentence.

Comment: remainder will hold "first" here.

Comment: Ahh, I played with it when I got home last night and fixed the example.  Try it now, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the delimiters first. There are a few problems with `strtok` (it modifies its argument, for one, which may land you in trouble). I prefer to read in the string and run a custom parser which may range from `sscanf` to a full-blown parser. Please post some more detail.

Comment: +1 `sscanf()` would work well, since I expect "words" means "anything not whitespace," making the conversion specifier easy, and should neatly avoid all the problems with `strtok()` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

[strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Actually, if you take out the link it still says `strtok`, so it's still an answer.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I answered this in 09, link still works!