# Compare words in two strings

Tags: c, string

I have made two strings. User can fill them both.

```
char text[200];
char text2[200];
```

I need to find similar words from both strings. For example,

Text= I am here for all my life

Text2= They are here to win us all

I need to program finds similar words like 'here','all'.
I tried like this but it don't found all words.

```
if(strstr(text,text2) != NULL)
```

and then printf but i think it isnt the right thing.

Comment: Do you know what `strstr` does?

Comment: The answer to this is not a fuction call but an algorithm you have to implement. So work on that: think about the problem and design a solution.

Comment: If there was a single function to do this, the odds are it wouldn't have been assigned to you as a project/homework/whatever it is. Check out the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) for `strstr` to understand why what you tried didn't work. There will be no occurrence of `text2`'s [full] content in `text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
char text[] = "I am here for all my life";
char text2[] = "They are here to win us all";

char *word = strtok(text, " ");

while (word != NULL) {
    if (strstr(text2, word)) {
        /* Match found */
        printf("Match: %s\n", word);
    }
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

It uses `strtok()` to read the sentence word by word, and `strstr()` to search for the corresponding word in the other sentence. Note that this is not very efficient, if you have big chunks of data you'll have to consider a smarter algorithm.

**UPDATE:**

Since you don't want to match embedded words, `strstr()` is not of much help for you. Instead of using `strstr()`, you have to use a custom function. Something like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
int searchword(char *text, char *word) {
    int i;

    while (*text != '\0') {
        while (isspace((unsigned char) *text))
            text++;
        for (i = 0; *text == word[i] && *text != '\0'; text++, i++);
        if ((isspace((unsigned char) *text) || *text == '\0') && word[i] == '\0')
            return 1;
        while (!isspace((unsigned char) *text) && *text != '\0')
            text++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The other code stays the same, but replace the call to `strstr()` by a call to this new function:

```
char text[] = "I am here for all my life";
char text2[] = "They are here to win us all";

char *word = strtok(text, " ");

while (word != NULL) {
    if (searchword(text2, word)) {
        /* Match found */
        printf("Match: %s\n", word);
    }
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Comment: It works, but there is one thing if 
text[]="Dog in the house"
text2[]="indoor skatepark"

Then match would be 'in'

Comment: Hummm, I thought you wanted that. You'll have to code your own version of strstr() to fix this. I'll update my answer in a few minutes with a workaround.

Comment: @user2883601 I updated my post with a workaround for this. Tested here, and seems to work, let me know if it's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use combination of `strtok()` and `strstr()`.

split `text` into tokens with `strtok()` and search that token in `text2` with `strstr()`

For safe Instead of `strtok()`  You can also use `strtok_r()`

Answer (score 1):

Break down `text` into words and search for those words in `text2` using `strstr`

Answer (score 0):

There are two threads that I think would be helpful for you.

[How to extract words from a sentence efficiently in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556616/how-to-extract-words-from-a-sentence-efficiently-in-c)

[Split string in C every white space.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513316/split-string-in-c-every-white-space)

Using [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) with a blank space as the delimiter seems like one appropriate solution to parse the two strings into words. It sounds like you've already implemented the second step (strsrt) effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Possible algorithm implementation:

- Get both strings from the user (Might be better to use `char **` instead of `char *`)
- Sort each string using [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)
- Start at the beginning of the smallest list of strings and begin your search

Note: It is possible to have the last step execute in `O(n)` time