# Find the same elements of two different arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have  two string arrays named `array[100]` and `array2[100]`, and the arrays values are assigned with `fgets(sentence1, 100, stdin);` , and `gets(sentence2, 100, stdin);`. The arrays may contain the sames words, or they may not.

How do you find the word that are the same in both arrays, and display the words in the output.

Thank you:)
p/s. I'm using pointers.

Comment: What do you want to do with the characters that are the same in both arrays(do you want to print them out without spaces, with spaces...) Please be more specific.

Comment: @SeanChen I want to display the same words of both arrays.

Comment: Then you should change "characters" in your question to "words". When you say characters, you mean displaying a, b, c is they are in both arrays. When you say words you mean cat, mouse, dog in both arrays. I assume that the words have spaces between them and them characters are each INDIVIDUAL characters. Please make your question more specific so others can answer them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare words in two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387737/compare-words-in-two-strings)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of strtok (re-entrant version) and strcmp.

Tokenize both the strings, then with a nested for loop use strcmp to compare each word of the first sentence with every word of the second sentence.